# VADER: Sentiment for each sentence

Tags: python, nlp, vader

I am new to python and I have a dataset that looks like this

[image]

I am extracting the reviews from the dataset and trying to apply the VADER tool to check the sentiment weights associated with each review. I am able to successfully retrieve the reviews but unable to apply VADER to each review. This is the code

```
import nltk
    import requirements_elicitation
    from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

c = requirements_elicitation.read_reviews("D:\\Python\\testml\\my-tracks-reviews.csv")
class SentiFind:
    def init__(self,review):
        self.review = review

for review in c:
    review = review.comment
    print(review)

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for i in review:
    print(i)
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(i)
    for k in sorted(ss):
        print('{0}: {1}, '.format(k, ss[k]), end='')
    print()
```

Sample output:

```
g
compound: 0.0, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.0, pos: 0.0, 
r
compound: 0.0, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.0, pos: 0.0, 
e
compound: 0.0, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.0, pos: 0.0, 
a
compound: 0.0, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.0, pos: 0.0, 
t
compound: 0.0, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.0, pos: 0.0, 

compound: 0.0, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.0, pos: 0.0, 
a
compound: 0.0, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.0, pos: 0.0, 
p
compound: 0.0, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.0, pos: 0.0, 
p
```

I need to customize the labels for each review as well to something like this

```
"Total weight: {0}, Negative: {1}, Neutral: {2}, Positive: {3}".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `review` that you've defined is a `string`, so when you iterate through it, you get each letter:

```
for i in review:
   print(i)

g
r
e
a...
```

Thus, you'll want the analyzer to go for each review:

```
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

for review in c:
    review = review.comment
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(review)
    total_weight = ss.compound
    positive = ss.pos
    negative = ss.neg
    neutral = ss.neu
    print("Total weight: {0}, Negative: {1}, Neutral: {2}, Positive: {3}".format(total_weight, positive, negative, neutral))
```